# Moderator message notification link to last non-mod message

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, ios-app

This is the workflow I experienced half an hour ago:

- In lock screen mode, a notification showing the first text lines of a new meta post is shown
- Opening the app, which has a familiar notification icon on it, also shows an unread message
- Opening the mail box the last non-mod message is shown as unread, even if it was cleared hours before
- Clicking the unread message, takes you to the expected comment, which was read before

This probably only applies to moderators using the app.